# Replacing anonynomous function while keeping all others from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm fairly new to `node.js`, `prototypical inheritance` and the `CommonJS` module patterns.
Maybe this question was answered a million times, but I couldn't find it, so even a link to the answer is considered an answer.

I have to wrap a module that has both named and unnamed functions, like this:

```
// a.js
function a(data) {
    console.log(data, 'A')
}

function b() {
     a('B');
 }

module.exports = a;
module.exports.b = b;
```

Given OOP background I would like to somehow *'inherit'* all the functions of the module while I want to override the anonymous function (I'd like to add some fields to the data).

**It is very important that after overriding `function a` in the new module `function b` should use the overridden method and not the original one.**

```
// 'inherited.js'
var a = require('./a');

function overriddenA(data) {
    data.myAddedValue = 'an important addition';
    a(data);
}    

// I would like to export all other functions and properties of the original module
[magic that overrides the anonymous function while keeping all other functions as they are]
```

From where I use it should look like this:

```
var decoratedA = require('./inherited');

decoratedA('stuff'); // it calls overridden function
decoratedA.b();      // it calls the original a.b() which in turn calls the overridden function
```

### Solved our original problem

Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459267/2018771 - still if you have any comment on the abstract problem, please answer the question. We are curious :).

Comment: Both functions in your module example are named functions, so that aspect of your question is a little unclear.

Comment: @Pointy but where you use it does not have the name `a` right? So you can't say `require('./a').a = function () ...`, or I misunderstand something. Which is quite likely.

Comment: You can copy the properties from `a` to `decoratedA`, so that `b` would be available to `decoratedA`

Comment: OK, I see; well being "named" or not really doesn't affect that. (Inside of function "b", the name "b" is indeed still visible. It's a local private symbol, distinct from the "b" symbol outside of its scope. Just a detail.) Anyway, I'm still not sure I see what you're doing; you can't make a function do something different from what it did at the point of its definition, but you can wrap it in a new function that delegates and does other stuff.

Comment: I clarified what I want to do with a comment. As @thefourtheye suggested I would like to get all other functions and properties as the original module, and wrapping that "unnamed" function. So you can use this wrapped module as the original one, just swapping what module you required.

Comment: @thefourtheye It looks like a brute a force solution to me - isn't there a language element for this? Maybe it's the standard pattern in node.js - I don't have the experience to tell.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to somehow 'inherit' all the functions of the module while I want to override the anonymous function

Wanna use some dark magic? Then [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is the way to go:

```
var a = require('./a');

function overriddenA(data) {
    data.myAddedValue = 'an important addition';
    a(data);
}    
overriddenA.__proto__ = a;

module.exports = overriddenA;
```

The cleaner method, without actual inheritance, would be to just copy over all properties from `a` to `overriddenA`. You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (or a shim), [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), or a simple `for in` loop for that.

Comment: Nice dark trick, but didn't solve the problem. It is very important that `b()` calls `a()` in the example. With your solution I will have the new function + all the old ones, but `b()` calls the **original** `a()`.

Comment: @atoth: Uh, it wasn't clear from your question that you needed that. But no, that's outright impossible to change. The `b` function will always have the original `a` in its scope. You'd have to overwrite `b` as well to change anything. Your other options are to do source code manipulation (even darker), or change the structure of `a.js` to be more extensible in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, it needed clarification. I have updated the question. Unfortunately `a.js` is a 3rd party package.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fork their code then. What exactly is it that you need to override, and why? Can you link the source code in question? Maybe we can find a better solution.

Comment: I update my question as my colleague looked at the code and found out it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile we have solved our original problem which was adding a special header to every calls of `request` library. In that implementation there were functions like `get()`, `put()`, `post()`, etc. that used one function: `function request(...)` which was exported `module.exports = request`

My understanding was that I had to replace that `request(...)` with our own, adding our header and then calling the original function.

But we were lucky because `request(...)` returned an object which we could modify according our needs:

```
Request.prototype.__originalInit = Request.prototype.init;
requestPromise.Request.prototype.init = function(options){
    console.log('adding our stuff');
    this.__originalInit(options);
};
```

So this solved the problem for us, but not the original question.

Comment: Are you using the request library?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/request     
Then there is no need to go through all that trouble just to add a header just use ...   

`request( { url : "my url",  "headers" : { "Host" : "myhost.com",  Accept : "*/*" }}  ); `

  I suggest you read the API of for a library that you use.   nodejs is all about the API

Comment: I know I could do that, but what you suggested gave us an idea. Thanks!